# Generic Function with Omit gives could be instantiated with an arbitrary type error

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to setup a generic function that maybe removes a field in a generic type.

```js
type MaybeID = {id?: string};

withoutID<K>(model: K & MaybeID): K {
    if (model.id) {
      const { id, ...data } = model;
      // Type of data is Omit<K & MaybeID, "id">
      return data; // Error here
    }
    return model;
  }
```

I get the error:

> Type 'Omit<K & MaybeID, "id">' is not assignable to type 'K'.
> 'K' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Omit<K & MaybeID, "id">'.

If I maybe add the `id` property but then remove it, do I not get `K` back? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is an error because `K` might include ID. If it does, the resulting object will **not** have the `id` property in it. The correct return type should be `Omit<K, 'id'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I not get `K` back?

No, you don't — and here's why:

> Note that I'll use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) on the returned value in your function to override and suppress the compiler diagnostic — in order to illustrate why it's not what you expect:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAkgESgXigbygSwBMB+ALigGdgAnfAOwHMoBfAbgCh3RJYB7QiABsAwrzpVqcesCxQAShADGvaoQA8ABWq9I1UAGkIIADRQArnQDWdXgHc6APigAyWAmToO7AGYXFwfDEoW3xgAAteM2B0KDV9BwAKAFt+IXJ9FzckVDQASnTcdigCbyhk1MEAOiJcwuLi5XEZPCJTSvbCOGA4FlkUgUEOeqhqCGAzajooTu6oOAoofSGWIpGxian+oQ5mTkaqKC3BWRxVonIAcgvjVYktHUuwoUFeYJVBQmv2Zkou-ApvPgIAsYBVRE1JNIvPsZKMKGZBDJsCFwpFomhygNcstigB6XEAPWIezEFF4ggglReDASFyIFwIUzhCOApmZiOqhGxUHxUBoZmgACJBewgA)

```ts
type MaybeID = { id?: string };

type ModelConstraint = Record<PropertyKey, unknown> & MaybeID;

function withoutID <K>(model: K & MaybeID): K {
  if (model.id) {
    const { id, ...data } = model;
    return data as K;
  }
  return model;
}

const model = {
  id: '',
  strProp: 'hello world',
} satisfies ModelConstraint;

const result = withoutID(model);
    //^? const result: { id: string; strProp: string }

console.log('id' in result, result.id); // true ""
```

The example above uses your function's implementation code. You can see that, when an empty string is provided, the result of the conditional check `if (model.id)` is `false` (see [runtime type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion), [`if...else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else), [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)).

This results in the effect that the code in the corresponding block is never executed, and the object is returned as-is: including the `id` property and empty string value.

Instead of using a conditional that coerces the type of the value, you can use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to determine if the property exists in the object (regardless of the type of its value): this better represents the intent of your code.

It then becomes self-evident why `Omit<K, 'id'>` is suggested: the omission of the `id` property in the returned value is the type that is returned from the function (because the implementation code ensures that it isn't there — see [`Omit<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) in the TS handbook):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAkgESgXigbygSwBMB+ALigGdgAnfAOwHMoBfAbgCh3RJYB7QiABsAwrzpVqcesCxQAShADGvaoQA8ABWq9I1UAGkIIADRQArnQDWdXgHc6APigAyWAmToO7AGYXFwfDEoW3xgAAteM2B0KDV9KAgAD2AIOkIKPgERMQkpOmAHAAoAW34hcn0ASnIAeWLQuNMAciImpxx2KAJvKEKWwiaCOihSrMrcTq6oZXEZPCJTADplwjhgOBZZUaEOKahqCGAzamHV9d2WSYOjk5GywQ5mThmqO6zZDq6iciam40mJFodD8wkJBLxgipBAN-sxKGt8BRvPgIBkYPdRLNJNIvC8ZAcKGZBDJsCFwpFomgSvdKhcugB6ekAPWIzxyvEEEEW4IYfVaQ32qKJwFMhQJwqgcAycDoIEqiyItKgjKg3jgggo0AsAmRdAghHYQA)

```ts
type MaybeID = { id?: string };

type ModelConstraint = Record<PropertyKey, unknown> & MaybeID;

function withoutID <K extends ModelConstraint>(model: K): Omit<K, 'id'> {
  if ('id' in model) {
    const { id, ...data } = model;
    return data;
  }
  return model;
}

const model = {
  id: '',
  strProp: 'hello world',
} satisfies ModelConstraint;

const result = withoutID(model);
    //^? const result: { strProp: string }

console.log('id' in result, (result as any).id); // false undefined
```